# How to Use Specific Profile with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, arguments

Iam trying to use a specific Profile of my Chrome Browser.

I know you have to make use of the `user-data-dir` flag and add the path to your Profile.

Let's say I have a Profile named `Profile 1`.

I've tried doing this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1")
```

My problem is that Selenium by default Appends `/Default` to this value, therefore not finding a valid Profile.

So far the Only workaround I've found is to create a default folder in my Profile Directory, and then Copy all files in this directory to the Default folder I created.

When I do this, This runs perfectly. But I don't like the Idea of having to do this process.

Please how else can I solve this without having to duplicate my Profie Files?
Thanks.

## EDIT

The answer in that question doesn't work.. Whoever answered the question said to put `Profile <num>` as part of `user-data-dir` which **DOESN'T** work!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I thought `user-data-dir` takes the path to your profile, but I was wrong.

All I had to do was give `user-data-dir` my chrome data which is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` and then add `profile-directory` argument which takes name of the profile.

## Final Code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument(r"profile-directory=Profile 1")
```